# Country Name field in CA generated by openssl is encoded as PRINTABLESTRING while other fields are UTF8STRING

Tags: encoding, openssl, x509certificate, pkix

I am generating a CA certificate with openssl version 1.0.1e with the following commands:

> ```
> openssl ecparam -out ec_key.pem -name secp384r1 -genkey
> openssl req -new -key ec_key.pem -x509 -nodes -days 1460 -out ec_ca_cert.pem
> ```

At the end of this process I enter DN fields as follow:

> ```
> Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:US
> State or Province Name (Full Name) [Some-State]:Florida
> Locality Name (eg, city)[]:Miami
> Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:Coca Cola
> Organization Unit Name (eg, section) []:Drinks 
> Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:Miki 
> Email Address []:
> ```

I convert the ec_ca_cert.pem certificate to DER format:

> ```
> openssl x509 -in ec_ca_cert.pem -inform PEM -out ec_ca_cert.der -outform DER
> ```

When I edit the ec_ca_cert.der file with an HEX editor, I can clearly see that the Country field is encoded as PRINTABLESTRING (Type=0x13) while all the other fields (Locality Name, Organization Name, Organization Unit Name, Common Name) are encoded as UTF8STRING (Type=0x0c).

Is there a reason for this, or is there a problem in my process, or an openssl issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the following answer in openssl-users forum:
"countryName is ALWAYS a PrintableString, and is ALWAYS 2 characters long.
See X.520 for a normative definition, included in RFC5280 for information.
"